# How to get Zoom in or Zoom out value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this plugin package `google_maps_flutter` where i can able to open maps and i followed every steps to show map in android and ios. But how to get the zoom value if i zoom in or zoom out in google map? Below is the sample dart code.

```
class GoogleMapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const GoogleMapPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GoogleMapPageState createState() => _GoogleMapPageState();
}

class _GoogleMapPageState extends State<GoogleMapPage> {
  late Position userLocation;
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  Future<Position> _getLocation() async {
    try {
      userLocation = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
    } catch (e) {
      userLocation = null as Position;
    }
    return userLocation;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _getLocation(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: LatLng(userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude),
                  zoom: 15),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
I solved by using this line of code.

```
onCameraMove:(CameraPosition cameraPosition){
     print(cameraPosition.zoom);
  },
```